# Google maps search box FOUC

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When the map is loading the location, e.g. waiting for geolocation access, the search box renders on the edge of the map like this

[image]

Anyone know any tricks to stop this ?  Either don't show the box at all, or put the box in the map where it should be.

As for code, even the Google example suffers from this problem: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete

Comment: Please could someone explain the downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is happening is that the `<input>` element is part of the HTML markup, and is visible on the page also before google maps has finished initalization. It is not an error or even unexpected behavior.  You have two options :

**1**) set the `<input>` box `visibility` to hidden :

```html
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" 
placeholder="Enter a location" style="visibility:hidden;">
```

and show the box as the last thing in `initialize()`

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {
  input.style.visibility='visible';
});
```

see fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/xkAaJ/**

**2**)  create the input box by code. Remove the `<input>` markup and replace

```js
var input = /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */( 
      document.getElementById('pac-input'));
```

in `initialize()` with

```js
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.id="pac-input";
input.className="controls";
input.type="text";
input.placeholder="Enter a location";
```

see fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/wy6X3/**

The code examples is based on the google places example you are refering to in the question.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up finding your first solution on my own, but I prefer the second solution.  Also note that `placeHolder` should be `placeholder`.

Comment: That's interesting.  For me, I can override placeholder with no problems.  In your jsfiddle link for example I can change it whatever I want.

Comment: You are right, didnt correct "placeHolder" and when its not set google assigns the local language version of "Enter a location". Everything goes wrong today :(